# Binary number representation

Tags: c, binary, floating-point, cpu-architecture

First, this isn't a question about precision or anything like that.

My question is, how does the compiler decide how to represent a number?

Let's take C for example. I write

```
double d = 4.5632;
```

How does it pick its binary representation? I know it's not represented exactly, so how does it choose the closest representable number? Is it done at compile time? Is it done by the CPU or the OS?

**Please** only answer if you know how this happens, answers like "don't worry about it" are not helpful. Also, "it depends on the platform" isn't helpful also, you can pick a platform and explain for that.

Comment: Computers do not "pick" binary representation - hardware designers and compiler writers do. Take a look at [this standard](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754-2008).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The compiler doesn't decide (typically).  The CPU (typically) has a floating-point unit, which requires floating-point values to be represented in a particular format (it's typically [IEEE-754](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754)).  Of course, it's possible to emulate an entirely different architecture, in which case the compiler/emulator author is free to pick an entirely different representation.  But this isn't typical.

As to how the specific lexical representation `4.5632` is converted to the underlying representation, that's specified by the C standard.  So from section 6.4.4.2 of the C99 standard (I've highlighted the most relevant part):

> The significand part is interpreted as a (decimal or hexadecimal)
>   rational number; the digit sequence in the exponent part is
>   interpreted as a decimal integer. For decimal floating constants, the
>   exponent indicates the power of 10 by which the significand part is to
>   be scaled. For hexadecimal floating constants, the exponent indicates
>   the power of 2 by which the significand part is to be scaled. For
>   decimal floating constants, and also for hexadecimal floating
>   constants when FLT_RADIX is not a power of 2, **the result is either the
>   nearest representable value, or the larger or smaller representable
>   value immediately adjacent to the nearest representable value, chosen
>   in an implementation-defined manner**. For hexadecimal floating
>   constants when FLT_RADIX is a power of 2, the result is correctly
>   rounded.

This will be done at compile-time (although the standard doesn't mandate that).

Comment: And it depends on the standard

Comment: This doesn't answer my question - how? How does it know 3.14 is to be represented by 0100111010.... or whatever?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that particular conversion is done at compile time, since `double d = 4.5632;` is a compile-time constant. What's compiled into your code is the representation of this value in the floating-point format used by the target architecture. In case of 32-bit IEEE-754 representation, this is `0x409205BC`. How the CPU "knows" that this is a value somewhat close to 4.5632 is dependant on the floating-point standard itself. Again, in the case of 32-bit IEEE-754, we have one bit for the sign, eight bits for the exponent, and 23 bits for the mantissa.

When it comes to rounding, there are several methods that can be applied. The IEEE-754 specification mentions four methods : round to nearest, round to zero, round to negative infinity, round to positive infinity.

Answer (score 0):

The compiler generates a program to run on a platform. The platform might have existed before the compiler, or vice versa. Binary representations of everything compose the ABI, which is essentially a specification of the compiler's output. In the end, things are done however they're done, for whatever reason, but hopefully there's an ABI to say exactly what happens.

In practice, almost all platforms implement floating-point arithmetic according to IEEE 754, aka IEC 559. This fairly old international standard defines what the bits of a floating-point number mean, and how the program decimal representation should be rounded to a floating-point value.

Platforms with no FPU will still usually pack and unpack bitfields from IEEE 754 numbers in software, since they are likely to appear in binary form in files.

Platforms with limited requirements for interoperability and numeric precision, such as GPUs, are likely to relax the standard of precision demanded by IEEE 754, but the numeric ranges it defines are the best for a wide variety of applications.

Of course, you can't depend on anything if you want ultimate portability. But it's a safe bet that the conversion from decimal to binary FP (supposing the FPU itself isn't decimal) is performed at compile time.

Answer (score 0):

For your specific example, yes the binary representation is encoded at compile time.  It likely calls a C library (atod, sscanf, etC) and whatever that library does with truncation or rounding is what happens.  And the compilers "features" or "rules" for what it does are not necessarily the same runtime rules that happen when you do the same thing.  You should never check for equivalence with floating point anyway but if you were to take a compile time value and then feed the program a string and convert that runtime (say you pass the value 4.5632 on the command line and use one of the library calls) you wont necessarily get the same floating point value.  I have seen the compilers (gcc, etc) do a really bad job with compile time constants so as a rule, for a number such as yours (not much in the mantissa) my preference for accuracy is to do this:

```
double d; int a;
a 45632;
d = a;
d/=10000;
```

And even if it optimizes it tends to get a better, more accurate, answer.

You do run the risk of hardware+OS error in the int to double conversion, Hauser made some comments about FPU errors tending to be in the int to float and float to int operations.  Even if at compile time I would assume the compiler would literally do two int to floats then the divide rather than do a string to float directly as your code had.

It has been a few years since I demonstrated all of this, maybe the compilers have gotten better (doubtful).  Hopefully the hardware has gotten better (likely, it used to be very rare to find an fpu without easy to find bugs).

Comment: IEEE 754 floating point format is normally used.  But it depends on the hardware if there is a hardware FPU on your system, then whatever format that hardware uses is likely what the compiler compiles to.  If it is a soft fpu then it is whatever format the soft fpu wants.  IEEE is the harder/slower/less reliable format due to the myriad of features.  ti dsp format for example is significantly cleaner, faster, more reliable, but has no rounding or  infinity or nans.

Answer (score 0):

Your particular example is converted by the compiler because it is a decimal literal. You want specifics, so let's pick gcc. It does the conversion in [real.c](http://opensource.apple.com/source/gcc/gcc-1765/gcc/real.c) (I don't know if that's the current version but that was the first copy I found through Google), in a function called real_from_string(). It essentially does the conversion with a long division: in your case, 45632/10000.

(Decimal to floating-point conversion is quite involved; check out [my blog](http://www.exploringbinary.com/topics/#correctly-rounded-decimal-to-floating-point) if you want to learn more.)